# Clinical study with a washout period: treatment effect - how to analyse data to assess differences between groups?

Tags: mixed-model, interaction, stata, treatment-effect

I have data on an old (non-randomised) clinical study to run secondary analyses - an exercise.

The trial had three periods as follows:

- Time zero: first group receives the drug (baseline information on
  both groups)
- 6 months: first group stops taking the drug, second
  group starts taking the drug
- 12 months: second group stops taking the drug

As this is not a randomised trial - despite little difference between the two groups - I think it is important to control for covariates.

My question is: how to assess the impact of the drug considering the washout period?

Using Stata (but I guess the equation can be easily read also for those using a different program) I specified the following mixed-effect command for a continuous outcome:

```
mixed outc i.treatment##c.time i.sex age risk_score_baseline disease_duration || id:
```

The output gives me three parameters of interest, and I would like to double-check whether I am doing this right:

- i.treatment: fixed effect treatment - which should be the overall difference between treated and untreated over the study period
- c.time (time as continuous): change by unit of time
- interaction term time continuous # treatment categorical: this should be the slope if I am not mistaken. And this should measure the amount of change for those taking the drug within 6 month period (the time unit). Am I correct?

Am I doing right to only look at the results of the interaction terms? What happens if the interaction is significant and the fixed effect treatment alone is not significant?

Considering the study has a washout-period the mixed effect specified this way was the only thing I could think of to analyse the data. Any other suggestion?

Thanks

Comment: When is the study analyzed, at 12m? What do you mean by washout? For drugs, washout would more refer to the drug model of washout type than the drug itself, although one can think of drugs as washing out. What effect are you measuring and what pharmacokinetic/pharmacodynamic relationship does that have to the drug? Lots of information missing, also, asking questions about "How do I use Stata?" is not a statistical question and is out of scope, so maybe delete that part of the question.

Comment: What is the study outcome? Did dropout occur for death or other reasons?

Comment: For washout period I meant that initially one group takes the drug and, when this group stops taking it, the other starts taking it.
0 months: baseline measures taken - first group starts taking the drug
6 months: measures taken - first group stops, second group starts
12 months: measures taken - second group also stops taking the drug.

The drug is an enzyme and the outcomes are several, including blood cholesterol

thanks